How to run an inner "ServerT" with different context to the outer "ServerT"
We are writing custom servant combinators to handle various authorisation layers in our application. E.g. if you had a task management system, you might have an outermost scope where no authentication has been done, then the first layer would handle user authentication (which might give you access to some resources), a further layer might check your authorisation for a "project", which would create a new context, and so on.
The problem I have run into is that serveWithContext transforms the ServerT into a WAI.Application, which does not compose into layers in this way as we have broken out of servant-world entirely.
I think what I want to do looks something like this:
serveWithContext' ... (myOuterContext) $
  \userInfo -> serveWithContext' ... (mkNewContext userInfo) $
   ...

I can't work out the shape of the functions needed for this, however.
Motivation
The reason I need this to be constructed in layers is that we are using the ReaderT over IO pattern, and we construct different operational contexts at each layer (as parts of the application then can use mtl-style constraints to state their requirements). I cannot construct the inner operational contexts until I have passed through the various outer routing layers (like authentication, which adds user data to the context, or "project authorisation" which adds project data to the context, etc.).
This isn't to pass data to the handlers themselves, that's easy enough, but actually to pass server contexts to the inner combinators which they need to be able to run the checks in the route definition.
Current attempt
My current attempt at this looks a bit like this:
class Layer a where
  type family InnerContext a

  runLayer ::
    forall api ctx ctx' m env.
    ( HasServer (a :> api) ctx,
      HasServer api ctx',
      HasContextEntry ctx' (InnerContext a)
    ) =>
    Proxy a -> -- the outer api proxy
    Proxy api -> -- the inner api proxy
    (m a -> Handler a) -> -- the hoist
    ServerT api m -> -- the inner server to run
    Router env

I thought I had worked out the direction needed, but am now not even sure if it is possible.

I've never played with servant, so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but... can you just call your custom monad stack's run* function?

@DanielWagner it's a good question. The problem is that I can only construct that monad stack in subsequent routing layers as things like the authentication and authorisation get handled (the stack has auth* context built in), so I can do it with part of the stack, but not the whole thing.

To add to this, the real issue is that I can't construct new contexts in layers, because serveWithContext (which constructs the context) returns a WAI application, not a composable Server.

Ok, I think I know the shape of the solution, and also the shape of the question is wrong. I'll try to reform both this evening in case anyone else has this question, but basically the real problem is composing contexts at different stages of  routing.
